# `values` vs `list` for returning multiple values from Lisp form

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

What's the difference between using `(values …)` versus `(list …)` (or literally `'(one two three …)`) to return multiple values from a `lambda` (or other implicit `progn`)? Does it create some special glue to `multiple-value-bind`? Superficially, I can't see any difference and am curious whether it's merely a convention for multiple return values.

Comment: Can the downvoter take the time to drop a note on how to improve this question?

Comment: +1 @Giorgio — i know i asked this a bit hastily, however there's not exactly a lot of model Lisp questions (on many sites, not just SE), and i'd appreciate any pointers to help build the community! :]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This question has been already answered on SO: [values function in Common Lisp](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22796346/850781).

Briefly, multiple values is a facility to return many objects without allocating extra memory.
E.g. [`floor`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_floorc.htm)
must return two values - quotient and remainder.
It can return a [`list`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/t_list.htm) (or a [pair](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/26_glo_c.htm#cons)) or it can return [two values](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/26_glo_m.htm#multiple_values).
In the former case it will have to allocate a cons cell on each call, in
the second it will not.

This means that multiple values have [certain limitations](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/v_multip.htm)
(one cannot return more than 20 values *portably*).

Comment: I'd be quite happy if you pulled the entirety of your answer here too (and linked back to it).  Note also that if you use the link provided in 'share' (`http://stackoverflow.com/a/22796346/850781`) as the link instead, it would allow you to get the Announcer badge if people click through it.

Comment: Note that it's completely implementation dependant how the values are actually stored. It could be registers, or on the stack, or a thread-local vector, or a series of thread-local vectors for different amounts of values, or a top-of-the-stack-allocated vector, or a heap-allocated user-hidden vector type (thus no longer saving you from consing), or a freshly consed list in an interpreter, or a combination of these, or yet something else.  I've seen a few of these in actual implementations.